# AngularJS translate pip directive applied to ng-options for loop in dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, translation, ng-options

I am using a dropdown menu in AngularJS and I need to translate its items.

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="top: 10px;">
              <label>{{'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_TITLE' | translate}}</label>
              <select class="form-control text-uppercase" ng-init="usersCtrl.userFilter.showOnlyNotDeprovisioned = true"
                      ng-model="usersCtrl.userFilter.showOnlyNotDeprovisioned"
                      ng-options="i.v as i.k | translate for i in [
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ACTIVE', v:true},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_DEPROVISIONED', 'v': false},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ALL', 'v':undefined}]"
                      ng-change="usersCtrl.getUsers(usersCtrl.userFilter)">
              </select>
            </div>
```

In particular:

```
ng-options="i.v as i.k | translate for i in [
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ACTIVE', v:true},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_DEPROVISIONED', 'v': false},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ALL', 'v':undefined}]"
```

I tried also:

```
ng-options="i.v as (i.k | translate) for i in [
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ACTIVE', v:true},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_DEPROVISIONED', 'v': false},
                      {'k':'DROPDOWN_DEPROVISIONED_ITEM_ALL', 'v':undefined}]"
```

But in both cases this is what I get:

[image]

The `something | translate` directive is working in other parts of the code.